# AD authentication for AppDynamics using Rest/python SDK

Tags: python, appdynamics

I am able to authenticate and fetch details using local user account using the python SDK of App Dynamics is there a way to authenticate using AD from python API or using the REST/curl.

Comment: Yes, that is possible. For a more detailed response add more details about your scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the response we have an on premise App Dynamics controller which is mapped to Azure AD so to fetch the details i should be using the AD credentials instead of the local credentials so how can i use the AD credentials using the REST/Python SDK

Answer (score 0):

I think everything you need is described [here](https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO42/Using+the+Controller+APIs) 
Basically you need to do the following:

```
<your_username>@<your_accountname>:<your_password>
```

probably in your case it is

```
<your_username>@customer1:<your_password>
```

via CURL it looks like this

```
curl --user user1@customer1:secret http://demo.appdynamics.com/controller/rest/applications?output=JSON
[
    {
    "description": "",
    "id": 5,
    "name": "ECommerce_E2E"
  },
    {
    "description": "",
    "id": 8,
    "name": "ECommerce_E2E-Fulfillment"
  },
]
```

You can find more information about the AppDynamics API [here](https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO42/AppDynamics+APIs)